# How get custom routes to show up in the google sitemap?

Tags: silverstripe, xml-sitemap

We are using the google sitemap module: https://github.com/wilr/silverstripe-googlesitemaps

We have a `TourPage.php` which has custom routes on its controller, in our `sitemap.xml` it shows the parent page fine, but no routes are showing up:

e.g At the moment it just shows:

```
website.com/tours/tour-name-1/
website.com/tours/tour-name-2/
```

but we want it to show:

```
website.com/tours/tour-name-1/
website.com/tours/tour-name-1/photos
website.com/tours/tour-name-1/details
website.com/tours/tour-name-1/reviews
```

...

```
website.com/tours/tour-name-2/
website.com/tours/tour-name-2/photos
website.com/tours/tour-name-2/details
website.com/tours/tour-name-2/reviews
```

etc

How do we achieve this?

```
class TourPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array('BrochureForm', 'brochure', 'brochure_thanks', 'details', 'photos', 'reviews', 'book', 'downloadItineraryFile', 'map', 'overview', 'getSlugName');

    public function photos() {
        if(!$this->canViewPage()) {
            return $this->redirect(ToursPage::getFirstPageLink());
        }
        return array(
            'MetaTitle' => $this->resolveMetaTitle('MetaTitlePhotos'),
            'Photos' => $this->TourPhotos(),
            'MetaImage' => $this->resolveMetaImagePhotos(),
            'MetaVideo' => false,
            'ImageSlug' => $this->getSlugName(),
            'SluggedImage' => $this->getImageBySlug(),
            'AbsolutePhotoURL' => $this->getAbsolutePhotoURL()
        );
    }


    public function index() {
        if(!$this->canViewPage()) {
            return $this->redirect(ToursPage::getFirstPageLink());
        }
        // Have to return something...
        return array();
    }

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        if($this->request->param('Action') == 'brochure') {
            Requirements::themedCSS('bootstrap.min');
            Requirements::javascript(THIRD_PARTY_PATH . 'javascript/chosen.jquery.min.js');
        }
    }

    public function overview() {
        if(!$this->canViewPage()) {
            return $this->redirect(ToursPage::getFirstPageLink());
        }
        return array();
    }

    public function details() {
        if(!$this->canViewPage()) {
            return $this->redirect(ToursPage::getFirstPageLink());
        }
        // Have to return something...
        return array(
            'MetaTitle' => $this->resolveMetaTitle('MetaTitleDetails'),
            'Photos' => $this->TourPhotos(),
            'MetaImage' => $this->resolveMetaImageDetails(),
            'MetaVideo' => false
        );
    }


    public function reviews() {
        if(!$this->canViewPage()) {
            return $this->redirect(ToursPage::getFirstPageLink());
        }
        return array(
            'MetaTitle' => $this->resolveMetaTitle('MetaTitleReviews'),
            'Reviews' => $this->data()->Reviews()->Filter('Disabled', 0),
            'MetaImage' => $this->resolveMetaImageReviews(),
            'MetaVideo' => false
        );
    }


    public function book() {
        // If we don't book, then head to the contact page
        if($this->ContactFormToBook) {
            FlashMessage::add('Please use the Contact Us form if you\'d like to book a ' . $this->Title, 'success');
            return $this->redirect(ContactPage::getFirstPageLink());
        }
        return $this->redirect(BookingPage::getFirstPageLink() . '?Tour=' . $this->ID);
    }

    /*
     * brochure page - with a check to ensure that they are allowed to view the page
     */
    public function brochure() {
        if(!$this->canViewPage()) {
            return $this->redirect(ToursPage::getFirstPageLink());
        }
        return array();
    }


    public function map(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
        if(!$this->isAllowedMap()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Link());
        }
        Requirements::javascript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&key=AIzaSyCNCBX_mLK0uuDElVttJVJgM2fuXIynv6E');
        Requirements::javascript(THIRD_PARTY_PATH . 'javascript/map.js');

        return array(
            'MetaImage' => $this->resolveMetaImageMap(),
            'MetaVideo' => false
        );
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That module provides the ability to include custom routes as described in the [docs](https://github.com/wilr/silverstripe-googlesitemaps/blob/master/docs/en/index.md).

Example below:

```
GoogleSitemap::register_routes(array(
    '/my-custom-controller/',
    '/Security/',
    '/Security/login/'
));
```

Comment: Right, so it would be a matter of having to loop over each TourPage link and then concat every route onto them? And pass that to the register_routes()? As there are 100 individual tours.